# PYTHON - socket "[Errorno 105] No buffer space available" after 10 hours execution

Tags: python, sockets, buffer, runtime-error

I implemented a code that sends pings to different destinations in a continuous way, but, after a 10 hours execution cycle, the socket I'm using is affected by some sort of aging that makes the application stop with a "[Errorno 105] No buffer space available". How can I MONITOR and SOLVE this problem?

Just for info, once opened, I use always the same socket to send and receive pings: could changing the socket periodically solve the problem?

### SENDER CODE

```
import socket

icmp = socket.getprotobyname('icmp')
self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW,icmp)

for target in target_list:
        #...
        packet = header+data
        while packet:
                sent = self.socket.sendto(packet,(target, 1))
                packet = packet[sent:]
```

### RECEIVER CODE

```
import select

whatReady = select.select([self.socket],[],[])

if whatReady[0] != []:
        for skt in whatReady[0]:
        #...
        (recPacket,addr) = self.socket.recvfrom(self.PACKET_SIZE+64)
```

NOTES:

1. `self.socket` is the same object reference for both modules.
2. I never close or change `self.socket` during execution.
3. self.PACKET_SIZE = 32 (byte)

Comment: Posting some code would help solve the issue.

Comment: It's a 2k lines code: I only added the relevant parts.

Comment: Is it the sender or the receiver that encounters the error after 10 hours?

Comment: The sender inside the for cycle. According to internet, it should be this error: " ENOBUFS - The output queue for a network interface was full. This generally indicates that the interface has stopped sending, but may be caused by transient congestion. (Normally, this does not occur in Linux. Packets are just silently dropped when a device queue overflows.)"

Comment: FWIW in our (non-python) code we treat ENOBUFS as a transient error; i.e. if a send() fails with ENOBUFS we simply call send() again and continue on as before.